# Can you have cellspacing between the rows in a html table without having it for columns

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am looking for a solution for having cellspacing between each of the rows of a table but not between the columns.  Is this possible?

Comment: I hadn't realised that this was so difficult to achieve, I'd assumed some combination of css (`margin: 1em 0;` and so on) would make it happen. Guess not... =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `border-spacing` is nice, but IE6/7 [doesn't](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html) understand that. If you want to cover them as well, then rather do:

```
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 10px solid white; /* Or any color which matches table's bgcolor */
    border-width: 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can separate rows in a table using the `border-spacing` property:

```
table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
}
```

This sets the space between columns to zero and the space between rows to 10px.  If you supply one argument, then that length will be applied to both the vertical spacing and the horizontal spacing; with two arguments, the first will set the horizontal spacing and the second will set the vertical spacing.